# Lateral control for autonomous vehicles

Tags: control, simulation, matlab, path-planning, autonomous-car

I am working on autonomous vehicle control, i used the kinematic bicycle model,

- For the speed reference I used a speed profile not a constant speed(given below [![speed][1]][1]
- for the steering angle I used the radius to generate the steering angle d=atan(L/r), you will find the code used below.
  where did i go wrong so that i don't have any pursuit ?
- the results of the (x,y) vehicle position (in blue) and the road (in red) are given by [![result][2]][2]
- Code:

`roadCenters = [114.0758 129.2616 -0.002332852;
123.7942 132.6021 -0.002582644;
133.8967 137.3962 -0.002888271;
137.0677 138.9055 -0.00298834;
150.6001 145.0092 -0.003429421;
173.4132 160.0353 -0.004368632;
285.7534 229.03 -0.01051842;
395.1082 301.1 -0.01935268;
454.6491 327.2592 -0.02460683;
461.2142 328.7133 -0.02515263;
471.513 329.7459 -0.02595824;
496.1926 330.8792 -0.02788709;
526.3301 325.9428 -0.030045;
555.0835 315.8794 -0.03197174;
626.267 278.9304 -0.03682783;
785.6708 195.2591 -0.05133038;
806.3408 188.8024 -0.05371195;
839.4267 183.6897 -0.0578257;
867.7778 186.2227 -0.06168913;
896.191 191.5745 -0.06577247;
967.1287 218.0381 -0.07697441;
1008.957 234.3338 -0.08402597;
1039.905 250.1733 -0.08959433;
1055.937 261.9383 -0.09269901;
1060.51 267.1768 -0.09367474;
1075.818 284.7013 -0.09699582;
1093.205 314.3776 -0.1013468;
1105.474 343.11 -0.1049445];

x=roadCenters(:,1);
y=roadCenters(:,2);

nPoints = size(roadCenters, 1);

theta = [0:0.1:2*pi, 0];

nCurves = nPoints - 2;
gridSize = ceil(sqrt(nCurves));

plotRow = 1;
plotCol = 1;
figure(1)
clf;
for currentPt = 1:nCurves
x0 = x(currentPt + 0);
x1 = x(currentPt + 1);
x2 = x(currentPt + 2);

y0 = y(currentPt + 0);
y1 = y(currentPt + 1);
y2 = y(currentPt + 2);

A = [2*(x1-x0) , 2*(y1-y0); ...
2*(x2-x0) , 2*(y2-y0)];

B = [((x1^2 - x0^2) + (y1^2 - y0^2)); ...
((x2^2 - x0^2) + (y2^2 - y0^2))];
X = (A^(-1))*B;
xc = X(1);
yc = X(2);

r = sqrt((x0 - xc)^2 + (y0 - yc)^2);
d=atan(L/r);
disp(d)
circle_x = r*cos(theta);
circle_y = r*sin(theta);

subplot(gridSize, gridSize, currentPt)
plot([x0, x1, x2], [y0, y1, y2], 'LineWidth', 1, 'Color', [0 0 0]);
hold on;
plot([x0, x1, x2], [y0, y1, y2], 'x', 'LineWidth', 1, 'Color', [1 0 0]);
plot(circle_x + xc, circle_y + yc, 'LineStyle', '-.', 'LineWidth', 0.5, 'Color', [0 0 0.8]);
axis equal
title(['Curvature at point ', num2str(currentPt)]);
end
t = (0:length(d)-1); % Create a time vector
D= timeseries(d, t); % Create a timeseries object
`

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you're looking for help with here because you seem to be asking two distinctly different questions in the same post:

1. How do I convert a polyline into a steering angle, and
2. How do I make the lateral control independent of speed?

For the first question, I would try to convert the polyline into a radius of curvature, and then convert the radius of curvature to a steering angle via Ackermann geometry (assuming it's an Ackermann-steered vehicle).

Assuming the vehicle starts at a point in the polyline, transform the next two points into vehicle coordinates, then [fit a circle to those points](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/213670/240336). This will give you the radius of curvature. Then you can [calculate the steering angle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/650912/126492) as

$$\mbox{atan}\left(\frac{L}{r}\right)$$

where $L$ is the wheel base (distance between front and rear axles) and $r$ is the radius of curvature.

For the question of making it independent of speed, what you're really saying is that you want to remove time as a factor, which is totally doable. Instead of having a PID response curve that plots reference and feedback versus time, you could use longitudinal position.

Instead of calculating PID terms with respect to time, try:

```
proportional_error = ref - fbk;
integral_error = integral_error + (proportional_error * dX);
derivative_error = (proportional_error - prev_proportional_error) / dX; 
prev_proportional_error = proportional_error;
```

Finally, if this were me, I would use the calculated steering angle as a "feed-forward" term that does the bulk of the steering work as a *proactive* control term, and then supplement that with the result of a PID control that's wrapped around the lane offset value as a *reactive* control term, like:

```
y_ref = 0; // Assuming 0 is the center of the lane
y_fbk = // lane position feedback from some sensor

desired_steering_angle = // calculated from polyline and vehicle geometry

dX = // new forward vehicle motion since last loop update

proportional_error = y_ref - y_fbk;
integral_error = integral_error + (proportional_error * dX);
derivative_error = (proportional_error - prev_proportional_error) / dX;

kP = // Proportional gain, this is a parameter you tune
kI = // Integral gain, 
kD = // Derivative gain

pid_output = (kP * proportional_error) + (kI * integral_error) + (kD * derivative_error);

steering_command = desired_steering_angle + pid_output;
```

and this should be something that performs consistently across a large variety of lane curvatures and vehicle speeds.

:EDIT:

Based on the update to your question, it looks like you're putting the entire x/y points array into the curvature equation, but I think you need to go point by point and reevaluate. In looking at the results here, you also have a pretty hard "knee" in the data where you go [0,0] to [2.8249,0] and then from there to [-34.4, 35.2]. You'll need to break up the path into smaller parts to get a smooth trajectory.

Here's some code that iterates across the points:

```
roadCenters = [0      0 0; ...
               2.8249 0 0; ...
               -34.4 35.2 0; ...
               -145 -57 0; ...
               -148 -211 0; ...
               -41 -326 0; ...
               165 -400 0; ...
               417 -425 0; ...
               950 -32 0; ...
               1034 111 0];

x=roadCenters(:,1);
y=roadCenters(:,2);

nPoints = size(roadCenters, 1);

theta = [0:0.1:2*pi, 0];

nCurves = nPoints - 2;
gridSize = ceil(sqrt(nCurves));

plotRow = 1;
plotCol = 1;
figure(1)
clf;
for currentPt = 1:nCurves
  x0 = x(currentPt + 0);
  x1 = x(currentPt + 1);
  x2 = x(currentPt + 2);

  y0 = y(currentPt + 0);
  y1 = y(currentPt + 1);
  y2 = y(currentPt + 2);

  A = [2*(x1-x0) , 2*(y1-y0); ...
       2*(x2-x0) , 2*(y2-y0)];

  B = [((x1^2 - x0^2) + (y1^2 - y0^2)); ...
       ((x2^2 - x0^2) + (y2^2 - y0^2))];
  X = (A^(-1))*B;
  xc = X(1);
  yc = X(2);

  r = sqrt((x0 - xc)^2 + (y0 - yc)^2);

  circle_x = r*cos(theta);
  circle_y = r*sin(theta);

  subplot(gridSize, gridSize, currentPt)
  plot([x0, x1, x2], [y0, y1, y2], 'LineWidth', 1, 'Color', [0 0 0]);
  hold on;
  plot([x0, x1, x2], [y0, y1, y2], 'x', 'LineWidth', 1, 'Color', [1 0 0]);
  plot(circle_x + xc, circle_y + yc, 'LineStyle', '-.', 'LineWidth', 0.5, 'Color', [0 0 0.8]);
  axis equal
  title(['Curvature at point ', num2str(currentPt)]);
end
```

And that gives this set of plots:

[image: Plot of curvatures]

You can see that knee in the first plot, and then also pay attention to the units here - the first plot has axes scaled in the tens and later plots are scaled in the thousands.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, and what i mean by the speed independent from the steering angle, when calculating the steering angle at several attempts it would not give me a path pursuit so i thought , the problem may be with my speed reference but since you made it clear can you please explain to me more about how to convert the polyline into a radius of curvature, because i tried this formula and i am sure its the curvature i got wrong.

Comment: @AsmaaGZ you said you tried it and you're sure the curvature is wrong; can you please *edit your question* to show what you tried and the answer you got?

Comment: thank you again for your help, I have have added the code and the results

Comment: @AsmaaGZ I updated the answer, please see if this is helpful.

Comment: your code was really helpful, I added some code lines to calculate the steering angle at each radius so that i get a path pursuit and i also modified the road into a better one ( you could see that in the edited question where i put the new result along with my program), now i am not sure where is the problem and why my bicycle model isn't following the road.